# BigQuery not so fast today - tables with just 1 row taking a minute to query

Tags: google-bigquery

We've been experiencing timeouts, and long running queries with BigQuery. The table is 1 row (8 bytes) and the query is taking on average 50 seconds.

This is causes issues with our applications, which are timing out after 10 seconds. They don't expect a query over 1 row to take that long.

Is there something wrong with BigQuery today?

Some example job ids:

1. job_TlXh5ISWUc6QXpf3HQ3KC-iRdRw
2. job_4OLNwAFN_j6mqMsnw2q8UUAJ528
3. job_3bZjpkVOfb55PZbldCwot53HqWA
4. job_V_EJzsuM9hjikBM-zQ_hCoEJNu8
5. job_66awPpXPPfd7WrDuRzYf7o3bKPs

[image]

Comment: As you probably know adding job IDs will help the BQ team to check what's been wrong.

Comment: You're right. My bad. Usually do, but forgot this time. Added one now.

Comment: Hi Graham, our oncall can look into the logs to see where the problem was.

Were you seeing similar minimum latency for other requests, or was the problem isolated to specific tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there was a temporary issue yesterday afternoon where some queries experienced added latency. I looked at several of your queries and they all appeared to have run during that time.

The issue was related to a blocking call that we were making to a monitoring service that was timing out. We've since fixed the issue. We're in the process of conducting an internal post-mortem to figure out how to prevent issues like this in the future.